# --ion-safe-area-top not working as it should on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework

I'm trying my ionic app on iOS and when I'm emulating an iPhone with a notch the top safe area is not present and the bottom one is too big.
Momentarily I disabled the bottom one and don't know what to do for the top one.
Even if I try to give the --ion-safe-area-top a value in pixel it does not change.
If you need more information I will happily give more.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community, Xhuliano! It would be handy to add the code you tried and the screenshot of results if possible

Comment: check this link "https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/safe-area-css-ios/194278/5" or share screen shot and you code for config.xml

Comment: For me the issue was rather stupid and trivial.  My `index.html` file was not in the proper place.  It was supposed to be at the top-level of the `public` folder, but it was actually nested within the `public/assets` folder. *facepalm*